# G++ on windows: cannot fild -llua5.1

Tags: linker, g++

Good morning,

I'm trying to build luabind using bjam binaries and g++ (mingw).

Lua root is in 'D:\Dev\lua-5.1.4\',

*.a file here: 'D:\Dev\lua-5.1.4\lib\libluadll.dll.a'

*.dll file here: 'D:\Dev\lua-5.1.4\lib\luadll.dll'

All these *.o files were compiled well, but when it started linking it, something went wrong:

```
gcc.link.dll bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\libluabindd.dll.a
d:/programms/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../../mingw32/b
in/ld.exe: cannot find -llibluadll.dll.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

"g++" -L"D:\Dev\lua-5.1.4\lib"  "-Wl,--out-implib,bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\
libluabindd.dll.a" -o "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\libluabindd.dll"  -shared -Wl,-
-start-group "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\class.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\
src\class_info.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\class_registry.o" "bin\gcc-ming
w-4.4.1\debug\src\class_rep.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\create_class.o" "b
in\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\error.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\exception_h
andler.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\function.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\
src\inheritance.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\link_compatibility.o" "bin\gcc
-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\object_rep.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\open.o" "bin
\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\pcall.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\scope.o" "bin
\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\stack_content_by_name.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\s
rc\weak_ref.o" "bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\src\wrapper_base.o"  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl
,-Bdynamic -llibluadll.dll.a -Wl,--end-group -g

...failed gcc.link.dll bin\gcc-mingw-4.4.1\debug\libluabindd.dll.a bin\gcc-mingw
-4.4.1\debug\libluabindd.dll...
...failed updating 2 targets...
```

So, I renamed libluadll.dll.a into lua5.1, lua5.1.a, but it's still prints the same error message.

Thanks, beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `-l{name}` directive searches for `lib{name}.dll` and `lib{name}.a`. So, yours should be `-llua`, not `-llibluadll.dll.a`.

Secondly, are Lua libraries compiled with g++ too? Object files and libraries compiled by different compilers are incompatible in general.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I suppose if I was compiling it using code::blocks + minwg, it should work if I compile it now using only g++.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the `g++` command line is wrong:

```
-llibluadll.dll.a
```

If you want to link against `libfoo.dll`, the right linker flag is `-lfoo` (no lib, no dll).

If you have a static archive and you want a static link, just name the archive, with no `-l` prefix (and specify a path if it's not found).